# How to override a function in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, overriding

As part of a message parser I have something similar to what is below, I want to be able to override some of the base class message functions as needed, but the override only works if I add a pass through function. I have lots of these functions and would like to not have to use a pass through function for every message function the child might override.

I know I could provide the functions that the child wants to override as part of the init append operation from the child, but the real messages are a lot more complicated than this simple example and doing that would break the rules I have set for the child classes.

First question is why does it not just work without the pass though, dictionaries are mutable, so the override should be called from the dictionary.

Second question, is there a solution that does not entail the pass though function or appending the override functions to the dictionary from the child init?

```
class Base():

    def set_enable_ind(self):
        print("using the pass through hack")
        self.set_enable(self)
        
    def set_enable(self):
        print("In base class set_enable")


    # base msg config dict
    msgConfig = {
            'setEnable':   (set_enable),
        }

    msgConfigInd = {
             'setEnable':   (set_enable_ind),
        }
    def __init__(self, msgConfig=None):
        # add the child's messages to the default ones

        if msgConfig:
            self.msgConfig.update(msgConfig)
            self.msgConfigInd.update(msgConfig)

    #this one calls the function directly
    def msg_recived(self,msg):
        self.msgConfig[msg](self)
        
    # this one calls the pass though function
    def msg_recived_ind(self,msg):
        self.msgConfigInd[msg](self)
        
        

class Child(Base):
    # override from base class
    def set_enable(self, data = None, header=None):
        print("In child class set_enable")
    
    # add my own
    def disconnect(self, data = None, header=None):
        print("In child class disconnect_connection")
        
        
    # each entry gets a function to call
    BtMsgs = {
        'disconnect'  : (disconnect),
    }

    def __init__(self):
        # call base class __init__ function first, adding my messages
        Base.__init__(self, Child.BtMsgs)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    child = Child()
    
    #these both work as expected
    child.msg_recived('disconnect')
    child.msg_recived_ind('disconnect')

    #this will always call the Base class function
    child.msg_recived('setEnable')
    
    #this will call the child function
    child.msg_recived_ind('setEnable')     

#output is as follow:
#In child class disconnect_connection
#In child class disconnect_connection
#In base class set_enable
#using the pass through hack
#In child class set_enable
```

Comment: Your question isn't super clear, but have you looked at defining the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) dunder method on your class? You can also use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#getattr)(or their `__setattr__()`, `__getattr__()` equivalents) Python built-in methods to make class method/attribute access more dynamic...

Comment: I'm not inheriting from dict, so none of those make any sense. And I think my question is clear, why does the non pass though dictionary call not call the overridden function. i.e. why does the output  read on line 4, "#In base class set_enable" and not 'In child class set_enable' as an overridden function would read.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `msg_recived` function always calls the `Base.set_enable` method is because of scoping. When you do:

```py
class Base:
    def set_enable(self):
        print("In base class set_enable")

    msgConfig = {
        'setEnable': set_enable,  # I removed parens here
    }
    ...
```

you are telling Python to reference the nearest-scoped `set_enable` function (the one right above the dictionary).

The reason your Child class never calls *its* `set_enable` method, is because you haven't updated the reference in its own `msgConfig` dictionary. Calling the `self.msgConfig.update` method is only *adding* the new key/val reference to the `disconnect` method of the `Child` class.

If you change the `Child.BtMsgs` attribute/dict to have new references, it will work:

```py
class Child(Base):
    ...
    BtMsgs = {
        'disconnect': disconnect,
        'setEnable': set_enable,
    }

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(Child.BtMsgs)  # This is Python3.X+ convention
    ...
```

Output:

```
In child class disconnect_connection
In child class disconnect_connection
In child class set_enable
In child class set_enable
```

This is because `'setEnable': set_enable` is now scoped to the one defined inside the `Child` class.

Regarding my original comment on your question about using `__getitem__`, `getattr`, and `setattr`:
You don't have to subclass `dict` for these methods to be useful.

```py
class MsgConfig:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for attr in kwargs:
            setattr(self, attr, kwargs[attr])

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__dict__.get(item)

    def update(self, d):
        if isinstance(d, MsgConfig):
            d = d.__dict__
        for k,v in d.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)


class Base:
    def set_enable(self):
        print("In base class set_enable")


    def __init__(self, msgConfig=None):
        self.msgConfig = MsgConfig(setEnable=self.set_enable)
        if msgConfig:
            self.msgConfig.update(msgConfig)

    def msg_recived(self,msg):
        self.msgConfig[msg](self)



class Child(Base):
    def set_enable(self, data = None, header=None):
        print("In child class set_enable")

    def disconnect(self, data = None, header=None):
        print("In child class disconnect_connection")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(MsgConfig(disconnect=self.disconnect))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    child = Child()
    child.msg_recived('disconnect')
    child.msg_recived('setEnable')
```

Output:

```
In child class disconnect_connection
In child class set_enable
```

You could try modifying or extending the above class to work for you to automatically pull in necessary message function pointers.

Comment: As I said, I knew adding the overrides to the child dict append would work, and looks easy for this simple approach, but in the real use case the dicts are multi level, and there are class Childs of Childs so it's not practical to do it this way.

Comment: Also with your second solution , using the MsgConfig class, not sure it's practical with 30-40 messages in both base and child classes, and that the real message dictionary is multi level.